# Specifying Encryption Algorithm of IDP and SP in Spring SAML

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I'd like to find out how to specify the encryption algorithm used by the IDP and SP. I've already read the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-key-management) and browsed for the entire day for an answer. The only thing that looks remotely familiar is the "signingAlgorithm" in the extended metadata section. However, I don't think that's it. My requirement is that the IDP and SP both use AES-256 as the encryption algorithm.

Any input on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring SAML currently doesn't support sending of encrypted AuthnRequests (or other messages sent from SP to IDP), but is by default able to decrypt messages encrypted using AES-256 sent from IDP to SP.

Comment: Thanks, will you be able to link me to the official source that states Spring SAML being unable to support sending of encrypted AuthnRequests? I just want a more official citation even though I notice you are the author of spring-security.

Comment: This information is not mentioned in the manual, or other Spring SAML documents, so I can't point you anywhere. Feel free to contact me at vladimir@v7security.com, I can communicate this information in official writing. We can also discuss adding support for such feature into the product through this channel.

Comment: Thank you for the response. One thing I'd like to solidly confirm is whether or not we can override the SP -> IDP communication to make it encrypted. As in overriding specific Spring classes instead of playing around with the configuration file.

Comment: As for official communication, an e-mail is not an option for me because I am asking on behalf of several parties who'd all appreciate a public official confirmation of this information. Do you think it'd be possible for you to add a post to http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/saml? Thanks!

Comment: E-mail directly from me is as official as it gets. The only other thing I can do for you is mention this fact in the manual.

Comment: The manual in master of Spring SAML now contains the following statement "The AuthnRequest message is sent unencrypted on message level. If needed, encryption should be provided by SSL/TLS on transport layer." Hope it helps you. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/commit/4f9be533a3e025c8f6d6639e2b78fb8122418812

Comment: Thank you. That is most helpful to us. :)